# Put multiple values from json to a text file

Tags: json, powershell

I want the result be like this inside the text file:
`Orbx ENGM Oslo Gardermoen Airport - Microsoft Flight Simulator 1.0.0`

**- Microsoft Flight Simulator** should be writhen between the values

Here is my json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": [],
  "content_type": "SCENERY",
  "title": "ENGM Oslo Gardermoen Airport",
  "manufacturer": "",
  "creator": "Orbx",
  "package_version": "1.0.0",
  "minimum_game_version": "1.30.12",
  "release_notes": {
    "neutral": {
      "LastUpdate": "",
      "OlderHistory": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Is it also posible to save the text file with some of the value of title like this: version_**engm**_msfs.txt

So far I got the file filled with one value using this code:

```
@ECHO off

Powershell "(Get-Content .\manifest.json|ConvertFrom-Json).title" >version_msfs.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Save the `[pscustomobject]` object (graph) that [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) parses your JSON file into an aux. variable.
- Use that variable to access the properties of the parsed-from-JSON object, and synthesize the output string via `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).
- Apply the same technique to determining the output file name, passed to the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet.

  - Note: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, `Set-Content` defaults to BOM-less UTF-8 as the character encoding; in *Windows PowerShell*, it is the system's legacy ANSI code page that determines the encoding; use the `-Encoding` parameters as needed (though note that in Windows PowerShell you cannot directly create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files).

```bash
@echo off

powershell.exe "$o = Get-Content -Raw .\manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json; '{0} {1} - Microsoft Flight Simulator {2}' -f $o.creator, $o.title, $o.version | Set-Content ('version_{0}_msfs.txt' -f (-split $o.title)[0])"
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks. Can you also help me with what code to use if you want it to execute only in all one level subdirectorys.